# Shell - Grep or else to get text in a string

Tags: shell, grep

Still a newbie here, with a problem.

I have a string that is the result of a dropbox_uploader operation:

```
$ PP_FILE=$(dropbox_uploader list | grep -iE "perfect")
$ echo $PP_FILE
[F] 2332 perfect.-dfdfd-dfgf-gdfg-d.txt
```

But I cannot manage to get the file name... whatever i try i have errors...

I tried:

```
$ var1=$(grep "perfect" $PP_FILE)
grep: [F]: No such file or directory
grep: 2332: No such file or directory
$ echo $var1
<blank>
```

Why ????

thanks

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using grep, you are trying search pattern "perfect" in the file,[F] 2332 perfect.-dfdfd-dfgf-gdfg-d.txt

If you are sure that the third index of var1 would be the file name, then you can do

```
echo  $var1 | awk '{print $3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to use of unquoted variable `$PP_FILE` in your grep command that has spaces also and shell is interpreting it as multiple arguments for `grep` command.

However to get filename you should rather use awk:

```
echo "$PP_FILE" | awk '{print $3}'
perfect.-dfdfd-dfgf-gdfg-d.txt
```

OR:

```
echo "$PP_FILE" | awk '$3 ~ /perfect/ {print $3}'
perfect.-dfdfd-dfgf-gdfg-d.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the file name in double quotes:

```
var1=$(grep "perfect" "$PP_FILE")
```

You don't need the quotes around `"perfect"` (but they do no harm).

If the file name doesn't contain the `[F] 2332` section, then you need to lose the first two fields.

```
PP_FILE=$(dropbox_uploader list | grep -iE "perfect" | awk '{print $3}')
```

The quotes around the file name then remain strongly recommended but not actually necessary for the sample shown.

Answer (score 0):

Because you force `grep` to open three files: `[F]`, `2332` `perfect.-dfdfd-dfgf-gdfg-d.txt`.

I assume that first two are actually some service fields and third token is what you want to put into `var1`

So, use `echo` to write variable contents to stdout, and `awk` to read them from stdin and pick third field:

```
var1=$(echo $PP_FILE | awk '{ print $3; }')
```

Answer (score 0):

your grep command:

```
grep "perfect" $PP_FILE
```

searches "perfect" word in the list of files in the PP_FILE variable, which is not what you want.

You should get the third element in the PP_FILE string:

```
$var1=`echo $PP_FILE | awk '{print $3}'`
```